# If I know the ratio of two variable differences, how to write it as a percentage increase?

Tags: percentages, ratio

I know that $ \dfrac{\delta x}{ \delta y} = 5.8,$ meaning that the change in $x$ is $5.8$ times the change in $y.$

Is there a way to write this as a percentage increase? For example, there is a '$p$' percent increase in the change in $x$ compared to the change in $y.$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\delta x=580\% y$

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking for. We don't usually speak of an "increase in the change in $x$ compared to the change in $y$." If you asked what percent increase the number $5.8$ represents relative to the number $1$, I would say $480\%$, because $1$ must be increased by $4.8$ to obtain $5$. That is usually appropriate when the two numbers refer to similar quantities, such as the price of gasoline in two different years. But $5.8$ is $580\%$ of $1$.

Comment: @DavidK I saw this formula that states: [1 - (y/x)] * 100 would give you the percentage... which would be 82%. I do not know the validity of that formula or where it comes from.

Comment: $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}=5.8$ gives not enough information to recover percentage increase ratio $\frac{\Delta x / x}{\Delta y / y}$

Comment: If you want to know what a formula means, edit the question to show the formula **and** show what was said about that formula in the place where you found it. It would be helpful to say exactly where that place was, too.

Comment: "Percentage increase" in isolation is an ambiguous phrase. Are you trying to say that some unknown value $\delta y$ has increased to another unknown value $\delta x$? Or are you trying to talk about the percentage increase in $x$ (not $\delta x$) and separately the percentage increase in $y$ (not $\delta y$)?